# What does patanjali mean by performing samayama on friendship?

Tags: shiva, yoga, meditation, yoga-sutras, patanjali

In patanjali yoga sutras patanjali told to concentrate on qualities of friendship, what exactly is quality of friendship, what exactly one have to focus on...

Answer (score 2):

Abbreviation used: Patañjali Yoga Sūtra - YS

*Maitrī* (friendship, loving-kindness, benevolence) is explicitly mentioned in YS (1.33, 3.23). The sūtra in question is YS 3.23 but 3.23 follows from 1.33, so it's imperative to state 1.33 first before explaining 3.23 w.r.t to the commentaries of Vyāsa and Vācaspati Miśra.

> maitrī-karuṇā-muditopekṣāṇāṁ sukha-duḥkha-puṇyāpuṇya-viṣayāṇāṁ bhāvanātaś citta-prasādanam (YS 1.33)

Trans. : By cultivating the attitude of *maitrī* (friendship, loving-kindness, benevolence) towards those who are happy, *karuṇā* (compassion) towards those who are in *duḥkha* (distress, unhappiness, suffering), *muditā* (sympathetic joy) towards those who are virtuous, and *upekṣā* (equanimity, indifference) towards those who are non-virtuous, lucidity arises in the *citta* (mind).

The sūtra here mentions the cultivation of four practices viz. *maitrī, karuṇā, muditā* and *upekṣā* to enhance lucidity (*prasādanam*), which is the prerequisite for attaining the steadiness of mind (*citta*). These 4 practices correspond exactly to the four *brahma-vihārās* outlined in many suttas of Pāli canon, namely, *mettā, karuṇā, muditā, upekkā.*

Vyāsa Bhāṣya on YS 1.33

> How does the sūtra advise one to attain the purification of *citta*?
>
> By cultivating the attributes of *mairtī, karuṇā, muditā* and *upekṣā* towards happiness, misery, virtue and vice respectively, the  *citta* is purified. Of these, one should cultivate *maitrī* towards all living beings who are endowed with comfort and pleasures, *karuṇā* towards those who are suffering, *muditā* towards those of virtuous nature and *upekṣā* towards those of non-virtuous nature. Upon cultivating one's *citta* thus, one's white characteristic increases, making the *citta* pure. Having become pure, it becomes one-pointed and attains steadiness.

Usually, the feelings of jealousy, anger, cruelty, malevolence towards different beings disturb the mind and prevent it from attaining concentration. So, it becomes important to cultivate the *brahma vihāras* to keep the mind pleasant and happy, free from any disturbing element, so that it can become one-pointed and attain steadiness.

Vācaspati Miśra in his *Tattvavaiśāradi* follows Vyāsa's bhāṣya on 1.33 and further notes that by developing *brahma-vihāras*, one is able to remove qualities pertaining to *rajas* and *tamas*, so as to aid in the manifestation of white characteristic of purity viz. *sattva*, through which one's *citta* attains one-pointedness and steadiness.

> maitry-ādiṣu balāni   (YS 3.23)

Trans. By [saṁyama] on *maitri* and other such things, strengths are acquired.

To understand *saṁyama*, check YS (3.4: *trayam ekatra saṁyamaḥ*) which defines it as the act of concentration when *dhāraṇā, dhyāna* and *samādhi* (listed in YS 3.1-3 before) are performed together, *ekatra*, on an object. The commentators such as Vyāsa and Vācaspati simply state that rather than laboriously list all three each time *dhāraṇā, dhyāna*, and *samādhi* are to be performed together, Patañjali has introduced a technical term, *saṁyama*, to refer to the application of the three of them in sequence.

In YS 3.23, the commentators understand '*maitri* and other such things' in this sūtra to refer to 1.33, where the *brahma-vihāras* are listed by Patañjali. By cultivating *maitri* towards those as prescribed in 1.33, and performing *saṁyama* on this feeling, the *yogī* attains what Vyāsa in his *bhāṣya* terms the " power of *maitrī* ". He/she becomes the well-wisher of all, say the commentators, can make the whole world happy, and his/her effort to win the *maitrī* of others will not be in vain. Likewise, by performing *saṁyama* on the feeling of *karuṇā* that the *yogī* is prescribed to cultivate towards those in *duḥkha* (1.33), the power of *karuṇā* arises. He/she can lift the *duḥkha* out of their pain, says Vācaspati Miśrā in *Tattvavaiśāradi*. By *saṁyama* on *muditā* towards the pious and virtous, one attains the power of *muditā*. The commentators note, however, that *saṁyama* is not directed towards the fourth prescription listed in 1.33 — *upekṣā* towards the non-virtuous — because *upekṣā* is not a specific feeling but an absence of other feelings; *saṁyama* would thus seem to require a distinct state of mind as an object of focus, otherwise the meditator has nothing on which to focus. This type of *saṁyama* is through the  sheer intensity of total absorption on a feeling such as those listed above, by which the *citta* of the *yogī* becomes completely pervaded and charged with that feeling that it emanates out and affects other people.
This is simply due to the fact that all feelings are potentially inherent in *citta* already, the *citta* is the seat of emotion. So, through *saṁyama*, the *citta* simply manifests what is latent within it.

##### References

- Bryant, E. F. (Trans.). (2009). *The Yoga sūtras of Patañjali : A New Edition, Translation, and Commentary with Insights from the Traditional Commentators*. North Point Press.
- Prasāda, R. (Trans.). (1998). *Patañjali's Yoga Sūtras with the Commentary of Vyāsa and the Gloss of Vācaspati Miśra*. Mushiram Manoharlal. https://archive.org/details/PatanjalisYogaSutraswithTheCommentaryOfVyasaAndTheGlossOfVachaspatiMisraRamaPrasadTranslation/page/n1/mode/2up?view=theater
- Arya, P.U. (Trans.). (1986). *Yoga-sūtras of Patañjali with the Exposition of Vyāsa: A Translation and Commentary. Volume I: Samādhi-pāda*. The Himalayan International Institute of Yoga Science and Philosophy. https://archive.org/details/yoga-sutras-of-patanjali-with-the-exposition-of-vyasa-volume-i/page/n3/mode/2up
- Bhāratī, V. (Trans.). (2001). *Yoga-sūtras of Patañjali with the Exposition of Vyāsa A Translation and Commentary. Volume II :Sādhana-pāda*. Motilal Banarsidass

Comment: Very nice post.

Comment: Thx this is quite helpful. Trying to do upeksha w/ evil types is quite challenging I will say 